# Download from Requester Pays S3 bucket using EC2 identity

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to list and download files from a [Requester Pays S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html):

```
aws s3 ls --request-payer requester s3://requester-pays-bucket/
```

I'm running this command from an EC2 instance, but it fails:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

The error is clear, however I'm still a little surprised. The goal of a Requester Pays bucket is to offload the cost of S3 data transfers to the requester. Since I'm initiating my request from EC2, my identity as requester should already be clear to S3, no?

Can S3 or the AWS CLI somehow automatically pick up my identity from the EC2 instance I'm running on? Or do I *have* to provide credentials in some explicit way?

Comment: To provide some background on what I'm trying to do here: I maintain [an open source tool](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock) that launches Apache Spark clusters on EC2. As a convenience for my users, I'm trying to [offer Spark and Hadoop releases in an easily-accessible S3 bucket](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock/issues/238) that the EC2 instances can download from as part of cluster setup.

Comment: Nick, silly question... does your instance have an associated [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)?  If so, does [`aws sts get-caller-identity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) work correctly?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Nope, no associated IAM Role. My hope was for AWS to somehow automatically identify me as the payer, but it seems I have to provide credentials either directly or via an attached IAM Role.

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly provide credentials of an IAM user which have access to your S3 bucket. Just go to IAM dashboard of your AWS account and create a new user which have **programmatic access** to s3. After this you will be provided with a **secret access key** and **access key ID**.

Then login into your EC2 instance, run command "aws configure" in your terminal and you will be asked for **access key id** , **secret access key** , **default region** if you want to provide ,just enter these details and you are good to go with your command.